# How do I write a Rational ClearCase config spec to checkout based on a directory?

Tags: clearcase

I am new to Rational and I have to add functionality to an existing program to support a new program.  The applications are small and in a directory structure, they are on the same level.  What I would like to do is - when I perform a CheckOut under the legacy application the files are checked out under a new branch. When I check out under the new application, the files are checked out under the standard /main branch.  Here's kinda what it looks like:

```
  /main
        /CGI_Legacy
              /CGI_Extended
  /NewApp
```

It is my job to create the CGI_Extended and NewApp applications.  CGI_Extended represents the new branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix directories and branches.

Branches are set in the [config spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm) of a ClearCase view, which, for base ClearCase view, would look like:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /MyVob/Legacy/... .../CGI_Extended/LATEST
element /MyVob/Legacy/... /main/LATEST -mkbranch CGI_Extended
element /NewApp/... /main/LATEST
```

See also:

- "[How config specs work](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcfg_hwcfgwrk.htm)"
- "[Writing config specs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/r_mstrshp_rqst_config_spec.htm) "

This won't create a directory `CGI_Extended`, and will keep the files in their original directory, but will create an new branch `CGI_Extended` on each checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree directories and branches don't mix, it was a bad depiction. One more issue, when I input your config spec above I receive a "syntax error on line 3, near column 0". Any ideas?

Comment: @jnbbender I had forgotten the '`LATEST`' at the end of the second selection rule. Plus, I assume a Windows like path, where you replace '`MyVob`' with the name of your Vob. In Unix, that would be `/vobs/MyVob/...`